# How do I get the default map using React Native?

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps

I have a button in my application that should open the default map app. The button's title also depends on the default map app. For example, if the default map app is Waze, then the button's title should be `Open Waze`, and so on.

Any thoughts on how I can do this in React Native? I know that on iOS you can't change the default map app, however, on Android it is possible to set a default.

Thanks!

Comment: did you find the solution for that? Basically I want to open navigation with default app, or to show the selection menu

Comment: I am looking for the same thing

Comment: @Amitk Has anyone found a solution for this? I'd like to show a selection menu of available apps.

Answer (score 1):

For any future people looking at @bisho99 comment above, the only way I've found to do it is to list the schemes you want to support in your expo config or plist, and then use something like `Linking.canOpenURL(appPath)` - this is an async function and you can try maybe 10 apps and then show whichever ones return true, or present an opinionated option as to what app you think your users should use.

Documentation: https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking#canopenurl

Example pseudocode:

```
const MAP_SCHEMES = [
    'waze',
    'citymapper',
    'maps',
    'applemaps'
];
async function returnPreferredMap(putPathHere) {
    const allowedMaps = await Promise.allSettled(MAP_SCHEMES.reduce((promises, scheme) => {
         return [...promises, Linking.canOpenURL(`${scheme}://${putPathHere}`)]
    }, []);
    return allowedMaps.reduce((map, result, index) => {
        map[MAP_SCHEMES[index]] = result;
        return map;
    }, {})
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a library like: https://github.com/flexible-agency/react-native-map-link

or you can use custom code such as:

```
const scheme = Platform.select({ ios: 'maps:0,0?q=', android: 'geo:0,0?q=' });
const latLng = `${lat},${lng}`;
const label = 'Custom Label';
const url = Platform.select({
  ios: `${scheme}${label}@${latLng}`,
  android: `${scheme}${latLng}(${label})`
});


Linking.openURL(url);
```

Comment: Thanks! But this does not answer my question. I would like to get the name of the default map app that the user has set on their Android device and use it in my button's title.